# A nice and fun problem: How many different figures can we obtain by coupling (q) squares and (t) triangles?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinations

How many different figures can we obtain by coupling the edges of **(q)** squares and **(t)** equilateral triangles with equivalent sides? with the following rules:

- Squares and triangles have equal sides.
- All squares and triangles must be fitted.
- The coupling of the polygons will be made by the perfect fit between their edges.
- Rotated or reflected figures should be considered the same.
- Figures obtained by the fusion or conflict between polygons should also not be considered.
- Consider only the figures formed in the plane (2D).

Let **T(q, t)** be the total figures obtained by combining q squares and t triangles, determine a generic formula for **T (q , t)**.

The figure below shows an example for a better understanding of the question:
[image]

Comment: You appear to be missing some for $T(2,2)$. The rightmost figure in the second row has two triangles adjacent to each other. Move the two joined triangles to a different adjacent edge (not the other end). There should be two ways to do this.

Comment: I doubt you can find an analytical solution for this. Calculating this number with a computer isn't that hard (efficiency is another story). One might also get interested in the asymptotic behaviour of $T(p,q)$, which is, I believe, $ O(C^{p+q})< O(T) < O((p+q)!)$

Comment: Very well observed InterstellarProbe! I corrected this by adding two more figures to the image. Thanks!